# Pandas: Select all rows with maximum column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe-

`my_df`-

```
user_id |  spend |  transaction_id |
--------+--------+-----------------|
1       |   45   |        12       |
2       |   33   |        45       |
3       |   12   |        33       |
1       |   22   |        56       |
1       |   77   |        99       |
2       |   44   |        68       |
```

My goal is to get all rows with the greatest `transaction_id` for each `user_id`.

So, I want my final result to look like this -

```
user_id |  spend |  transaction_id |
--------+--------+-----------------|
1       |   77   |        99       |
2       |   44   |        68       |
3       |   12   |        33       |
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `df.sort_values(['user_id','transaction_id']).drop_duplicates('user_id', keep='last')`

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research? For example, groupby() with `.max()` might work for you

Comment: @G.Anderson groupby() will cause it do drop the `spend` column but I want to retain it without any aggregation on it. @Quang Hoang's answer works perfect